# How can I do Passport Authentication on multiple users?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, mongoose-schema, passport-local

Here I have multiple users like Parent,Trainer,Provider.I wrote individual schemas, routes and verify codes for registration and login and for storing, collections also different for each.when I make to run the application it is properly running.And after that I opened the postman tool I registered as" parent" the response is "Registration Successfull" and login as parent I am getting token so that I can perform the functions what a Parent can do in my project.And after that I logout as parent.Next, when I try to registered as Trainer/Provider the response is "Unauthorized". But the fields what I am giving at time of registration are stored in respective collections in database.When I give same values what a parent gave at the time of registration to trainer registration and provider registration then the response is "Registration Successfull" when I give different values other than what a parent gave it shows me "Unauthorized".So, I want to know why this issue arises? And how can I fix this problem?

Here is my schema code

```
<!-- trainer schema -->
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');
var trainerUser= new Schema({
username:{type:String,required:true,unique:true},
email:{type:String,required:true,unique:true},
phone:{type:Number,required:true,unique:true    },
password:{type:String});
trainerUser.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
module.exports = mongoose.model('trainerUser', trainerUser);    

<!-- parent schema -->
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');
var User = new Schema({
    username: String,
    email:String,
    password: String,
    phonenumber:Number
   });
User.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
module.exports = mongoose.model('parentlog', User);

<!-- provider schema -->
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');
var User= new Schema({
username:{type:String,required:true,unique:true},
email:{type:String,required:true,unique:true},
phone:{type:Number,required:true,unique:true    },
password:{type:String});
User.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
module.exports = mongoose.model('User',User);
```

Here is my routes code for each module
//trainer route

```
<!-- trainer route -->
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var passport = require('passport');
var trainerUser = require('../models/traineruser');
var Verify    = require('./trainerverify');

<!-- GET users listing. -->
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});

router.post('/register', function(req, res) {
    trainerUser.register(new trainerUser({ username : req.body.username,email: req.body.email, phone:req.body.phone }),req.body.password,
      function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({err: err});
        }
        passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, function () {
            return res.status(200).json({status: 'Registration Successful!'});
        });
    });
});

router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    if (!user) {
          return res.status(401).json({
        err: info
      });
    }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({
          err: 'Could not log in user'
        });
      }

      var token = Verify.getToken(user);
              res.status(200).json({
        status: 'Login successful!',
        success: true,
        token: token
      });
    });
  })(req,res,next);
});

router.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
    req.logout();
  res.status(200).json({
    status: 'Bye!'
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

//parent route

```
const AuthenticationController = require('../controllers/authentication');
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var passport = require('passport');
var User = require('../models/puser');
var Verify    = require('./parentverify');

var mongoose=require('mongoose');

const requireLogin = passport.authenticate('local', { session: false });
router.route('/')
.get(function(req, res) {
    User.find({},function(err,users){
        if(err) {
            return res.status(403).json({
                err: 'You are not authorized to perform this operation!'
            });
        } else {
            res.json(users);
        }
    });
});
router.post('/register', function(req, res) {
    User.register(new User({ username : req.body.username,email:req.body.email,phonenumber:req.body.phonenumber }),
      req.body.password, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({err: err});
        }
        passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, function () {
            return res.status(200).json({status: 'Registration Successful!'});
        });
   });
});

router.post('/login', requireLogin, AuthenticationController.login);
router.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
    req.logout();
  res.status(200).json({
    status: 'Bye!'
  });
});
module.exports = router;
```

//provider route

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var passport = require('passport');
var User = require('../models/user');
var Verify= require('./userverify');

<!-- GET users listing. -->
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});

router.post('/register', function(req, res) {
    User.register(new User({ username : req.body.username,email: req.body.email, phone:req.body.phone }),req.body.password,
      function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({err: err});
        }
        passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, function () {
            return res.status(200).json({status: 'Registration Successful!'});
        });
    });
});

router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    if (!user) {
          return res.status(401).json({
        err: info
      });
    }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({
          err: 'Could not log in user'
        });
      }

      var token = Verify.getToken(user);
              res.status(200).json({
        status: 'Login successful!',
        success: true,
        token: token
      });
    });
  })(req,res,next);
});

router.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
    req.logout();
  res.status(200).json({
    status: 'Bye!'
  });
});
module.exports = router;
```

and `app.js` code is here

```
  var express = require('express');
    var path = require('path');
    var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
    var logger = require('morgan');
    var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var passport = require('passport');
    var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
    var config = require('./config');
    mongoose.connect(config.mongoUrl);
    var db = mongoose.connection;
    db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
    db.once('open', function () {
        <!-- we're connected! -->
        console.log("Connected correctly to server");
    });
    var users = require('./routes/users');
    var trainerusers = require('./routes/trainerusers');
    var pusers = require('./routes/pusers');
    var contacts=require('./routes/contactRouter');
    var student=require('./routes/studentRouter');
    var batch=require('./routes/batchRouter');
    var venue=require('./routes/venueRouter');
    var trainerrouter = require('./routes/trainerrouter.js');
    var report=require('./routes/reportRouter');
    var attendance=require('./routes/attendanceRouter');
    var app = express();
    <!-- view engine setup -->
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
    <!-- uncomment after placing your favicon in /public-->
    <!-- app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));-->

    app.use(logger('dev'));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use(cookieParser());

    <!-- passport config -->
    var User = require('./models/user');
    var trainerUser = require('./models/traineruser');
    var Puser = require('./models/puser');
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    passport.use(new LocalStrategy(Puser.authenticate(),trainerUser.authenticate(),User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(Puser.serializeUser(),trainerUser.serializeUser(),User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(Puser.deserializeUser(),trainerUser.deserializeUser(),User.deserializeUser());
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
    app.use('/users', users);
    app.use('/trainerusers', trainerusers);
    app.use('/pusers', pusers);
    app.use('/contacts',contacts);
    app.use('/student',student);
    app.use('/batch',batch);
    app.use('/venue',venue);
    app.use('/report',report);
    app.use('/trainer',trainerrouter);
    app.use('/attendance',attendance);

    <!--  catch 404 and forward to error handler -->
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
      var err = new Error('Not Found');
      err.status = 404;
      next(err);
    });
   <!-- error handlers -->
    <!-- development error handler -->
    <!-- will print stacktrace -->
    if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
      app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.json({
          message: err.message,
          error: err
        });
      });
    }
    <!-- production error handler -->
    <!-- no stacktraces leaked to user -->
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
      res.status(err.status || 500);
      res.json({
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
      });
    });
  module.exports = app;
```

Comment: why you have written { session: false } this in parent routes